# Duda ciclos Pyhton

Tags: python, bucle-for, condiciones, while, booleano

ayer hice un código de un programa en el que la máquina genera un número al azar entre 1 y 10 y el usuario tiene 3 oportunidades para adivinarlo. Hasta ahí todo teóricamente bien. Mi problema es que no me ha quedado claro por completo el uso de los ciclos (en este caso solo hago uso de un while y algunos if) pero tengo los siguientes problemas:

1: Si el usuario adivina el numero ya sea en el primer o segundo intento a pesar de que se muestra el mensaje que puse que se enviara cuando se acierta el número, el programa sigue imprimiendo que se introduzca un número

2: Quiero hacer un poco restringido el programa en plan si el usuario pone un número inválido (este sería mayor que 10 o menor que 1) se muestre un mensaje que diga "introduzca un número válido y se detenga el programa en ese mismo instante. Intente hacerlo con un for dentro del while pero si ponía un número invalido no se imprimía ningún mensaje

Aquí mi código en cuestión

```
""" Programa en el que el usuario debe adivinar el número generado por la computadora"""
import random
rndnum = random.randint(1, 10)
name = input("Dime tu nombre: ")
print("Hola,{} en este programa tendras que adivinar el número "
      "que ha generado la máquina entre 1 y 10 Tienes solamente 3 vidas".format(name))
maxVida = 3  # Numero maximo de vida
while maxVida != 0:
    n = int(input("introduzca un número: "))
    if n == rndnum:
        print("Felicidades, has acertado")
    else:
        maxVida = maxVida - 1
        print("No has adivinado, te quedan {} vidas".format(maxVida))
if maxVida == 0:
        print("el número era {} :P".format(rndnum))
```

**Aquí pongo lo que quise implementar para que se escribiera un número válido **

```
if n < 1 or n > 10:
    print("Introduzca un número válido")
```

Pd: Si fueran tan amables de explicarme que estoy haciendo mal y por que pese a que no se cumple una condición el código sigue corriendo o en otras palabras, si yo adivino el número en el primer intento por qué me sigue imprimiendo que introduzca un número.

Comment: El bucle `while` no sabe nada de si has acertado el número o no. Un bucle `while` se va a seguir ejecutando mientras la condición que le pongas sea cierta. En tu caso la condición es `maxVida!=0`, que no tiene en cuenta si has acertado o no. Podrías usar otro booleano que inicializarías antes del bucle `acertado=False`, y cambiar la condición del `while` para que sea `while maxVida!=0 and not acertado`. Dentro del bucle, cuando acierte, haces `acertado=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo encontré algunas posibles soluciones a tu problema.

1.- Yo utilicé **[BREAK](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-break-continue-and-pass-statements-when-working-with-loops-in-python-3-es#:%7E:text=En%20Python%2C%20la%20instrucci%C3%B3n%20break,se%20activa%20una%20condici%C3%B3n%20externa.&text=En%20el%20bucle%20for%20%2C%20existe,entonces%20el%20bucle%20se%20romper%C3%A1.)** para cerrar el ciclo cuando el usuario adivinara el numero, en pocas funcionas el BREAK lo que hace es que puede salir de un ciclo, tu solo hacías que se imprimiera que el numero fue correcto y seguía corriendo el ciclo.

2.- Para lo de la validación, se utilizó un if pero con **and**, ya que tu quieres validar que el numero sea mayor a 0 y menor que 11, si lo utilizabas con un OR, pues simplemente con que se cumpliera cualquiera de las dos, iba a entrar dentro del programa. Te pongo un ejemplo:
Si elijo el numero 20, este es mayor a 0, pero menor que 10, con un OR se está cumpliendo la primera condición, y ya con eso pasaría la condición del if.
Pero si pones AND, el 20 debe ser mayor que 0 y menor que 11. Entonces no pasaría dentro del if, y ya se imprimiría que escriba un numero correcto.

Adjunto código, si tienes alguna duda con mucho gusto te ayudo.

```
import random
rndnum = random.randint(1, 10)
name = input("Dime tu nombre: ")
print("Hola,{} en este programa tendras que adivinar el número "
      "que ha generado la máquina entre 1 y 10 Tienes solamente 3 vidas".format(name))
print(rndnum)
maxVida = 3  # Numero maximo de vida

while maxVida != 0:
    n = int(input("introduzca un número: "))
    if (n<11 and n>0):
        if n == rndnum:
            print("Felicidades, has acertado")
            break
        else:
            maxVida = maxVida - 1
            print("No has adivinado, te quedan {} vidas".format(maxVida))
    else:
        print("Ingrese un numero correcto")
    if maxVida == 0:
            print("el número era {} :P".format(rndnum))
```

Answer (score 0):

Para eso puedes usar sys.exit()

quedaría así

```
 import random
    import sys
    
    rndnum = random.randint(1, 10)
    name = raw_input("Dime tu nombre: ")
    print("Hola,{} en este programa tendras que adivinar el número "
          "que ha generado la máquina entre 1 y 10 Tienes solamente 3 vidas".format(name))
    maxVida = 3  # Numero maximo de vida
    while maxVida != 0:
        n = int(input("introduzca un número: "))
        if n == rndnum:
            print("Felicidades, has acertado")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            maxVida = maxVida - 1
            print("No has adivinado, te quedan {} vidas".format(maxVida))
    if maxVida == 0:
            print("el número era {} :P".format(rndnum))
```

Acerca del if o while, es que son parecidos pero tiene un objetivo diferente, el if es una condición que especifica si...  If y While son como primos, hacen condiciones parecidas, pero el if condiciona una consecuencia, y el otro una acción consecuencia que se puede ciclar mientras tu condición este activa.